# Problem in docker images it is not starting

Tags: php, docker

I made in my project nginx, mysql, phpMyadmin, encore and php images.
Just php and encore dosent work, they are successed built, but the are with red color.

The directory of the project:

[image]

that is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
 database:
   container_name: database
   image: mysql:8.0
   restart: always
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: alsbls
     MYSQL_DATABASE: infoSystem
     MYSQL_USER: alsbls
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: alsbls
   ports:
     - '4306:3306'
   volumes:
     - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

 php:
   container_name: php
   restart: always
   build:
     context: ./php
   ports:
     - '9000:9000'
   volumes:
     - ./app:/var/www/infoSystem

   depends_on:
     - database

 nginx:
   container_name: nginx
   image: nginx:stable-alpine
   restart: always
   ports:
     - '8080:80'
   volumes:
     - ./app:/var/www/infoSystem
     - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
   depends_on:
     - php
     - database

 phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
   restart: always
   environment:
     PMA_HOST: database
     PMA_USER: alsbls_root
     PMA_PASSWORD: alsbls_root
   ports:
     - "8081:81"

 encore:
   container_name: encore
   restart: always
   build:
     context: ./php
   volumes:
       - ./:/var/www/html
```

That is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
          
RUN apt update   \
            && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
            && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
            && pecl install apcu \
            && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
            && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
            && docker-php-ext-install zip
WORKDIR /var/www/infoSystem
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN git config --global user.email "devojob97@gmail.com" \
        && git config --global user.name  "alsbls"




FROM node:12.10.0
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]
USER node
```

that is the entrypoint.sh in the same dir of Dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Prevent container from shutting down
while true; do sleep 3600; done
```

I didn't receive any error message on the terminal.
Maybe some one now the issues.

Best regards

Comment: Which thing isn't starting?  Which thing is red, and what color should it be?  The last container you show here is an empty `node` container, with no application in it, that intentionally does nothing as its main process; does that have any value?  Can you reduce the question to a [mcve] including only the containers and setup needed to actually demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the docker log of the encore image the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" - Docker
```

And then I tried to use the following command outside of the container:

```
dos2unix your-file.sh
```

[This tutorial helped me to solve it:](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory-in-docker)